# Pull from gitolite in cron job

Tags: git, ssh, cron, gitolite

I want to setup a cron job that makes a production site pull from a gitolite repository.

The following command works in a non-cron-context:

```
# m     h       dom     mon     dow     command
*       *       *       *       *       cd /home/www/test/autopulling-site/ && /usr/bin/git fetch && /usr/bin/git pull
```

I am suspecting that the git operation doesn't work due to the SSH key not being sent correctly in a cron context. The logs show nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you set when you want it to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure of the user actually executing the `cron`.
It could very well be root in this case, which means you need to make to make sure the `$HOME` (when running from `cron`) does contain your `.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` files.

But if your private key is protected by a password, don't forget the cron session won't know about your ssh-agent: see "[Execute rsync command over ssh with an ssh agent via crontab](https://serverfault.com/questions/92683/execute-rsync-command-over-ssh-with-an-ssh-agent-via-crontab)" for a concrete example.
As noted by the [OP Harold Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496999/harold-smith), [**`keychain`**](https://serverfault.com/a/236437/783) was the missing element here.

Comment: I can clone and pull without the use of password, which means cron should be able to, also... right? Can I modify my $HOME param inside the cron job and add the .ssh folder? I just echo'ed HOME in the cron job into a file, and it shows my ~ folder (but not the .ssh folder).

Comment: Brilliant. Your URL put me on the right track! I installed keychain, and that worked. It is now getting access to gitolite. Thx! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what could be wrong

However, you could redirect the command's output to a file (eg `(cd && git pull && ...) &> path/to/file`) to see what it's printing.

Comment: Doesn't print anything to the file, altough it does get created.

Comment: use `&>` instead of `>`. `>` just deviates stdout, `&>` deviates both stdout and stderr

Comment: oh sorry, I should really test things before posting... You have to put brackets around the command, otherwise just the last command is redirected, I'll edit my answer...

Comment: The stderr contains: "Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly." So I guess it is related to the key...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Didn't know about the &> syntax, it helped a lot. As you can see, another answer turned out to solve the problem.

Comment: +1 for `&>` which I didn't know. I always did `2>&1 >` to merge the channels.